# How to close the script after pressing two keys?

Tags: python, pynput

Is there any way to fix this? If I press shift or alt on my keyboard the process kills itself.
Can I somehow change the code to work and kill the process only when I press those two keys at the same time?

I tried changing `and` to `+` or `&`, there is a error `"unsupported operand type(s)"`

```py
def on_release(keys): 
    if keys == Key.shift and Key.alt_l: 
        return False
```

Comment: Try to read about [hotkeys](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#global-hotkeys), they're the intended way to handle multiple inputs at the same time

Comment: Try `if keys == Key.shift and keys == Key.alt_l`